# Designing threaded mail interface in Android

Tags: android, performance, email, android-webview

I am trying to build a threaded mail interface in my mail app. As there can be any number of messages in a particular conversation, each message will be having a header and a body part. Now for the body part, whether I should use WebView for each message in that threaded mail? Because using multiple WebViews in a single activity will slow down the performance I assume. There can be 50 messages and each message will have one WebView attached to it.

Is there any other lighter control available in Android where I can render HTML instead of using WebView?

Comment: It might be easier to just concat all HTML into one webview instead of having a lot of webviews (or alternative compoments). More efficient (and use browser preloading priorities to your advantage), more GUI possibilities, and not that hard to implement i presume..

Comment: If I concatenate all HTML into one WebView, how will be able to create a threaded mail interface? I want to create a gmail kind of interface for showing threaded mail.